# an equivalent to matheclipse in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working with Android Studio and i want to use the library matheclipse.
Please, is there any library in Android Studio equivalent to "matheclipse" ?

```
import org.matheclipse.core.convert.AST2Expr;
import org.matheclipse.core.interfaces.IExpr;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.Parser;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.ast.ASTNode;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.ast.FloatNode;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.ast.FractionNode;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.ast.FunctionNode;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.ast.IntegerNode;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.ast.StringNode;
```

Comment: Can't you just include the library in Android Studio?  Nothing magical about Eclipse.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a description of what it does and why it isn't working for you in Android Studio.